# How does blunting work in Dungeon Raid?

Tags: dungeon-raid

I've been playing a litte while, raised Assassin to lvl 5 and unlocked a few more classes. But I still don't understand some of the upgrades. Is there a manual or reference anywhere that would explain these?

Blunting : Is this -1 attack for each monster, or the total of all monsters? I've never taken this because it seems like it would be a tiny difference even at mid-levels.

Comment: You might be interested in [this guide](http://iphonedevpinoy.blogspot.com/2011/02/dungeon-raid-strategies-tips-and-tricks.html) which is kind of a mishmash of a bunch of forum posts, or the [Dungeon Raid Wikia](http://dungeonraid.wikia.com/wiki/Dungeon_raid_Wiki) which seems a little anemic but might have some data worth reading.  Other than that, I can't find much else about the game from a strategy perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the guide link; that was helpful and I hadn't seen it before; I had seen the Wikia, however, and anemic is being kind ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blunting *permanently* reduces each enemy's attack value. So once you get to the point where skulls usually hit you a few times before you can deal with them, blunting can substantially reduce how much pain you're in.

Comment: I just found this out myself in a game last night; it worked very well with a couple upgrades in blunting

Answer (score 0):

Both blunting and spikes affect each monster by its value.  This is especially evident with spikes: when the monsters attack, you'll see some text next to each one stating how many hit points were lost due to the spikes, e.g. "Spikes: -2".

I don't remember off the top of my head what dexterity and repair do.  I guess I'll have to play it tonight and refresh my memory. <kbd>:)</kbd>